# applescript photoshop apply layer style inner shadow

Tags: applescript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I know this works with strokes but trying to do it with a inner shadow.
After these settings
[image]

I think the code is something like this

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    activate
    tell current document
        apply layer style current layer using "73 Px Inner Shadow 15% Fill Opacity"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using for this?

Comment: Working in Adobe Cloud or Photoshop CC

Answer (score 2):

I really think this is best done using JavaScript (which you can call from AS, of course, by text or file) using the fairly obtuse but powerful ActionDescriptor method. The best (arguably only) way to do this is by downloading the Scripting Listener plugin (see: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5428603) and using it to parse and steal bits of code and putting these parts in your own JavaScript code. This code can then be used on its own (.jsx files called from within PS) or by calling the JS code from AppleScript.

For example, Below is a script (which can be run as-is in PS CC) taken directly from the Scripting Listener log to make an inner shadow on the currently selected layer, with these settings: Blend mode "Darken", rgb color {111, 22, 3}, Opacity 44%, Angle 55 degrees, Distance: 66 pixels, Choke: 7%, Size: 88px (more info below script code):

```
// =======================================================
var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref4 = new ActionReference();
var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
var idLefx = charIDToTypeID( "Lefx" );
ref4.putProperty( idPrpr, idLefx );
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref4.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc8.putReference( idnull, ref4 );
var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idgagl = charIDToTypeID( "gagl" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc9.putUnitDouble( idgagl, idAng, 55.000000 );
var idScl = charIDToTypeID( "Scl " );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc9.putUnitDouble( idScl, idPrc, 100.000000 );
var idIrSh = charIDToTypeID( "IrSh" );
var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idenab = charIDToTypeID( "enab" );
desc10.putBoolean( idenab, true );
var idMd = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );
var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
var idDrkn = charIDToTypeID( "Drkn" );
desc10.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, idDrkn );
var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
desc11.putDouble( idRd, 111.002197 );
var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
desc11.putDouble( idGrn, 21.999664 );
var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
desc11.putDouble( idBl, 3.003845 );
var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
desc10.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc11 );
var idOpct = charIDToTypeID( "Opct" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 44.000000 );
var iduglg = charIDToTypeID( "uglg" );
desc10.putBoolean( iduglg, true );
var idlagl = charIDToTypeID( "lagl" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idlagl, idAng, 120.000000 );
var idDstn = charIDToTypeID( "Dstn" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idDstn, idPxl, 66.000000 );
var idCkmt = charIDToTypeID( "Ckmt" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idCkmt, idPxl, 7.000000 );
var idblur = charIDToTypeID( "blur" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idblur, idPxl, 88.000000 );
var idNose = charIDToTypeID( "Nose" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc10.putUnitDouble( idNose, idPrc, 0.000000 );
var idAntA = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
desc10.putBoolean( idAntA, false );
var idTrnS = charIDToTypeID( "TrnS" );
var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
desc12.putString( idNm, "Linear" );
var idShpC = charIDToTypeID( "ShpC" );
desc10.putObject( idTrnS, idShpC, desc12 );
var idIrSh = charIDToTypeID( "IrSh" );
desc9.putObject( idIrSh, idIrSh, desc10 );
var idLefx = charIDToTypeID( "Lefx" );
desc8.putObject( idT, idLefx, desc9 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc8, DialogModes.NO );

////////////////end script///
```

This helps to clarify what some of those cryptic codes represent: http://www.pcpix.com/photoshop/char.htm

**[edit May, 2017]** The link above is now dead. The info now lives on https://pastebin.com/h9bK3m8D and the original is archived via the "wayback machine": https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20140709161028/http://www.pcpix.com/photoshop/char.htm

If you go this route (and really, I think it is currently the only way to get such a level of control over certain actions), you should be aware that the log needs to live on the desktop, and fills up indiscriminately, so I end up emptying it fairly regularly (and/or turning it off). I realize you may be more comfortable in AS than in JS, but if you learn how to write JS scripts (or even write them on the fly using AS), you become nearly all-powerful (and with great power comes great responsibility). Sometimes you can take out parts of the log-written code and make the code more "efficient", but (obviously, perhaps) mistakes can leave you with broken code and generic errors.

**[edit]** It is probably best to use, instead of the charIDToTypeID() method, for transfer mode, the stringIDToTypeID() method. Without getting into why, I'll just say that it is easier. Just use "camelCase" versions of the transfer modes, a la:

```
var idDrkn = stringIDToTypeID( "darken" );
```

or

```
//changed variable name to better reflect a generic
var transferModeID = stringIDToTypeID( "colorDodge" );
desc10.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, transferModeID );
```